Always getting SignatureDoesNotMatch error for get_presigned_url for file upload
When I'm using python SDK client to generate presigned_url instead of file upload this URL, when used throws an error SignatureDoesNotMatch
I'm running Min.io server locally using start_minio.sh script
#!/bin/bash
MINIO_ROOT_USER=admin MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=password minio server /opt/minio --console-address :9001

I'm generating presigned_url using main.py
import logging
from minio import Minio
import datetime

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

LOGGER_PREFIX = "MINIO_WITHOUT_DOCKER"

def main():
    ACCESS_KEY = "admin"
    SECRET_KEY = "password"
    MINIO_API_HOST = "localhost:9000"

    merchant_id = "test_bucket"

    client = Minio(MINIO_API_HOST, ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY, secure=False)

    found = client.bucket_exists(merchant_id)
    if not found:
        client.make_bucket(merchant_id)
    else:
        logger.debug(f"{LOGGER_PREFIX}: Bucket {merchant_id} already exists")

    url = client.get_presigned_url(
        "PUT", merchant_id, "test.md", expires=datetime.timedelta(hours=5)
    )

    logger.debug(f"{LOGGER_PREFIX}: url == {url}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

When method argument for get_presigned_url changed to GET and the file exists in the backet the correct URL returned
My OS is Fedora 39, kernel 6.8.9-200.fc39.x86_64 (64-bit)
Original issue on github https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/19728
